# What's the right way to write my data access layer's methods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Is this good enough ? do I need to add anything or remove anything ? like a rollback to my Sql Queries ? add catch() ?  should my function accept only the property that I need or the object it self ? and how can I let the presentation layer know that the function's code was executed with no errors .. should I make it book instead of void or what ?

```
    public static void DeleteAllCabinFeaturesFromACruise(int CruiseID)
    {
        string commandText = "DELETE FROM Cruise_Features WHERE CruiseID = @cruiseId";
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);

        try
        {
            using (connection)
            {
                using (command)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cruiseId", CruiseID);
                    connection.Open();
                    command.ExecuteScalar();
                }
            }
        }

        finally { connection.Close(); }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using `using` correctly. The idea of `using` is to wrap some resource, that needs to be released in a safety-west, that protects it from exceptions. So, the correct way of using `using` (ha-ha) is the following:

```
using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)){
{
    using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection)){
        //your code here
    }
}
```

The second issue is that you are executing your query as if it should return Scalar value. It's OK, but I think it's better use just `Execute`: `command.Execute();` And, if you want some error handling, you'd better wrap

```
connection.Open();
command.ExecuteScalar();
```

in a `try ... catch` block like you have. Like this:

```
//I would place it inside inner-most using block, but nothing wrong placing it outside
try{
    connection.open();
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cruiseId", CruiseID);
     command.Execute();
}
//this catches ALL exceptions, regardless of source. Better narrow this down with
//some specific exception, like SQLException or something like that
catch (Exception e){
    return false; //or whatever you need to do
}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you and yh the ExcuteScalar was a just a mistake thank you .. but how about this part "and how can I let the presentation layer know that the function's code was executed with no errors .. should I make it book instead of void or what ?" !?

Comment: The simpliest way is to change the return value type to bool. If you need more than just success/failure, you could introduce some `Enum`. And if you need to return some data from the function, you can distinguish between success and failure by returning null. But in your case, I would just return true/false.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the try...finally block. The "using" will take care of disposing the connection for you.

**EDIT**: As chibacity says, you should initialise the connection in the using to ensure correct disposal. Your error-handling (to prevent the users seeing the exception details) should be done in your UI layer, not your data-layer. It is entirely appropriate for a data-layer to throw exceptions.

```
string commandText = "DELETE FROM Cruise_Features WHERE CruiseID = @cruiseId";

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    // Your code.
}
```

For a simple query like that a rollback is probably not necessary - the query will either succeed or fail. For a more complicated query, a rollback would be necessary if you wanted to ensure that operations were atomic.

Comment: It's just not about the disposing .. I'm concerned about any errors happen. I don't want to just let the user see the error!

Comment: Although as the connection is initialised outside of the using and there are statements before the using, in theory there could be an exception before the using block is ever entered. Best to initialize in using statement.

Answer (score 1):

> and how can I let the presentation layer know that the function's code was executed with no errors?

This really boils down to how you want to handle these cases in general.  One rule of thumb is to ask yourself a question; are you expecting an error to occur significantly often, or not?  So, for example, if the method should only fail if there was a communication error, then it's perfectly fine to throw an exception to the front-end.  If, on the other hand, the delete operation can fall over because of various business rules that need to be validated (or, say, foreign key violations), then you should probably not throw those as exceptions.  In the latter case, your method should return some information about success (simplistic version: a boolean, complex version: your own "OperationResult" class).

I'm simplifying things a lot here, but I believe these rules of thumb are valid.

EDIT:  When I say "then it's perfectly fine to throw an exception to the front-end", I mean - throw it to the front end, but have the front-end handle it gracefully!

Answer (score 0):

connection.Close() is redundant - using(connection) will dispose and close it.
Also, connection.Open() is usually placed in the beginning - to verify connection with the server .

Comment: Yh but I need to put finally block! .. anyway I was doing the Try-Catch-Finally the wrong way, I got the tip now and I'll edit it .. but about placing the connection.Open(); on the beginning I just thought I'd add my commands then open the connection so I could minimize the time of the connection being opened .. what do you think ?

Comment: I usually do connection.open at the *last possible moment*, so I think OP did that part correctly.  (What does 'verify the connection' with the server' mean during runtime?)  Good advice on the using() though.

Comment: I didn't get it! .. so is it okay to open the connection at the last step ?

Comment: It is a matter of personal preference, I guess. You can open connection at any point, connection, by itself, does not take much resources, unlike a transaction. On the other hand, from all the thing that can fail network-related resources are most probable, so it makes sence to verify it before you perform all data preparation(in your case it is just a few statements).